# Using code constant in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this XAML code:

```
<ListBox DataContext="{Binding Tables[Suppliers]}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
</ListBox>
```

In the project I have the following code:

```
namespace Suppliers
{
    class DBServer
    {
        public const string TableSuppliers = "Suppliers";
    }
```

How can I use Suppliers.DBServer.TableSuppliers in the XAML page instead of hard-coded Suppliers:

```
{Binding Tables[ ??? ]}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this what is inside [] is a string you can always use a constant like
{x:Static c:Constants.X}

Comment: How exactly? Can you give me the code for my case? I tried different ways, but lisbox remais empty.

Comment: I'll try to test it in your case. I have never used brackets in binding path before so I don't really know how that works, but if this can't be done via the shortened notation it's probably possible to do "the hard way"